# Block matrices: Prove that $ \det \begin{bmatrix} A & B\\ B & A \end{bmatrix}\neq \det(A^2-B^2) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that $ \det\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
B & A 
\end{bmatrix}\neq \det(A^2-B^2)$ using the following matrix product $ \begin{bmatrix} I & B\\
0 & A - B\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A+B & 0\\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix} $

I don't even know where to start here. Can someone please drop some hints?

Comment: It is not clear what the matrix product presented has to do with the rest of the question. To show that the equality fails, you need a single counterexample; the product does nothing to indicate that such an example exists or how one would find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the expression $A^2 - B^2$ is only interpretable if $A,B$ are both square. So, I presume that $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same size.

**Hint:** We will have $\det \pmatrix{A&B\\B&A} = \det(A^2 - B^2)$ whenever $AB = BA$. A suitable counterexample exists with $A,B$ of size $2 \times 2$.

A further hint: we may select an example where $A$ and $B$ both have $3$ zero-entries.